# How do I model a stored procedure using Entity Framework 7 (EF7) in ASP.Net 4.6 using MVC and VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

In my web application project in VS2015 I am unable to create an EF model (EF7 version 6.1.3 installed) so I did this in another project (Templates -> Web -> ASP.NET Web Application -> ASP.NET 4.6 Template -> MVC Web Application) in VS2015 instead.

I was able to create a .edmx model and the resultant model created (by right-clicking on model and choosing ADO.NET Entity Data Model) looked like this, however this seems to have been created against EF6 packages:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Linq;

public partial class Transactor_SupportEntities : DbContext
{
    public Transactor_SupportEntities()
        : base("name=Transactor_SupportEntities")
    {
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<SP_CMA_Insert_Endorsement_Result> SP_CMA_Insert_Endorsement(string in_Endorsement_Code, string in_Endorsement_Title, string in_Endorsement_Text, string in_Product_Type, string in_Insurer_ID, string testModeYN, string iD_Suffix, Nullable<bool> in_Deleted, string in_Portfoliokey, Nullable<bool> in_Abivalue, string in_Endors_Linktype_ID, ObjectParameter out_Return_Message)
    {
        var in_Endorsement_CodeParameter = in_Endorsement_Code != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("In_Endorsement_Code", in_Endorsement_Code) :
            new ObjectParameter("In_Endorsement_Code", typeof(string));
....
```

Now, back in my web application project the `DbContext` only has a using as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
```

and when I try to copy the `ObjectResult<SP_CMA_Insert_Endorsement_Result>` and the rest VS2015 will not build the project because `ObjectResult` cannot be found in the using.

Can anyone help? All I need to do is to execute a stored procedure that inserts a row (as well as doing some necessary code) from within my controller and return a result. I have looked into various other methods of executing a stored procedure but EF7 does not support any of them?

Many thanks for all potential help!